# ggplot only black dots and no colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I have a dataframe in R as this (only sample posted here):

```
              DE      logFC     pval log2fc_color  rank
1    Upregulated  3.4958900 264.1088      #00519e   110
2    Upregulated  2.9649858 254.4343      #00519e   222
3    Upregulated  1.5794640 246.1799      #00519e   988
4    Upregulated  1.6678800 235.9541      #00519e   901
5    Upregulated  3.9374453 229.3586      #00519e    62
6          Top10  6.2492052 227.5845      #d51030     4
7          Top10  7.4608894 153.1061      #d51030     1
8          Top10  6.4259618 135.0821      #d51030     3
9          Top10  5.9704932 118.9760      #d51030     7
10         Top10  6.0201382 112.0736      #d51030     6
11 Downregulated -2.6035129 311.1072      #00519e  2624
12 Downregulated -3.8199728 306.3362      #00519e  3023
13 Downregulated -2.8384308 299.8498      #00519e  2749
14 Downregulated -2.9654265 299.6843      #00519e  2804
15 Downregulated -5.4785903 297.3173      #00519e  3135
16            NA -0.8830659 189.6105      #a7a7a7 17041
17            NA  0.9867408 181.4278      #a7a7a7    30
18            NA -0.9681908 170.5315      #a7a7a7 17357
19            NA  0.8636595 166.6765      #a7a7a7   451
20            NA  0.9811910 165.4120      #a7a7a7    44
```

and I am trying to do a volcano plot. I would like to color by different category of DE and I also have the color defined in the log2fc_color column. However, when I try to plot using the following command, I am only getting black dots.

```r
ggplot(df.t1, aes(x=logFC, y=pval, fill=log2fc_color)) + geom_point()
```

or

```r
ggplot(df.t1, aes(x=logFC, y=pval, fill=DE)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `color=log2fc_color` instead of `fill`. The default "points" only have a color aes.

Comment: Each of the `geom_*` help pages have a specific list of `aes`thetics that they understand/use; for instance, [`?geom_point`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html) lists: *'x'*, *'y'*, 'alpha', 'colour', 'fill', 'group', 'shape', 'size', 'stroke'; so yes, `fill=` is listed, but it is only relevant for specific `shape`s. One such example is listed in the help page, `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(shape = 21, colour = "black", fill = "white", size = 5, stroke = 5)`; most shapes do not really take advantage of `fill`, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things going on here:

1. `geom_point` can use `fill=`, but for most `shape`s it has no visual effect; for this, you either need to shift to using `colour=` or shift to a `shape=` that uses the fill attribute (e.g., `shape=21`);
2. Based on the `#rrggbb` nature of your `log2fc_color`, I believe you want the literal colors in the column, not a color-factor based on the categorical values of the strings; wrap it in `I(.)` to force the colors themselves.

```r
ggplot(df.t1, aes(x=logFC, y=pval, color=I(log2fc_color))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot2 with literal color assignment]

Or, using `colour=DE` and manual colors, which adds a legend:

```r
ggplot(df.t1, aes(x=logFC, y=pval, color=DE)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = c(Upregulated = "#00519e", Top10 = "#d51030", Downregulated = "#00519e"),
    na.value = "#a7a7a7"
  )
```

(Use `scale_colour_manual(guide = FALSE, ...)` if you want to suppress the legend in this case.)

[image: ggplot2 with colour scale and legend]